# (Node.js) Trouble with SSL Express Server

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https, server

I have the following code:

```
const http = require('http');                            
const https = require('https'); 
const server = http.Server(app);                         // ssl commented
const socket = require('socket.io')(server);             // ssl commented
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const fs = require('fs');

const PORT = 80;

// we will pass our 'app' to 'https' server
// const server = https.createServer({
//    key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/configuration/key.pem'),
//    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/configuration/cert.pem'),
//    passphrase: '<you wish!>'
// }, app)
//
// server.listen(PORT, function(){
//   console.log(`Listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
//   //vncClient = new WebSocket.Server({server: server});
//   vncClient = new WebSocket.Server({port: 3000});
//   vncClient.on('connection', new_client);
// });
// const socket = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(PORT, function(){                          // ssl commented
  console.log(`Listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);  // ssl commented
  vncClient = new WebSocket.Server({port: 3000});        // ssl commented
  vncClient.on('connection', new_client);                // ssl commented
});                                                      // ssl commented
```

When I switch the commenting (i.e. actual commented lines are uncommented and the "ssl commented" lines are actually commented), I get the normal console output (no errors) but nothing renders in the browser. Why is it that I can generate an `http` server but not `https`? I generated the `.pem`'s with `OpenSSL`

Comment: The way you are trying to create is not right, if you are using Websocket, why you need socket.io. I did not understand your code. Also have a look at this https://blog.zackad.com/en/2017/08/19/create-websocket-with-nodejs.html

Comment: @Sohan `socket.io` and `WebSocket` here have entirely different use cases. The creation of the web socket server is simply a function call for once the server starts listening to initialize a vnc client. As stated, things work perfectly when just using `http`. If it helps, ignore the vnc client declaration.

Comment: Did you tried above example in link, what happens if you remove the websocket releated code. Also make sure you are able to accessing https on proper port?

Comment: @Sohan I just removed the `WebSocket` code and got the same result. What do you mean by "proper port"? Can https servers only run on certain ports? I know that generally they run on `81` but do they HAVE to?

Comment: I will try this morning and let you know

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run the HTTPS server using node `https` module. 
Generated self signed certs using following steps:

`openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes -keyout example.key -out example.crt`

**Make sure for self signed you have proper CN names. In my case it was localhost**

Here is the sample code:

```
var app = require('express')();
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
var path = require('path');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const fs = require('fs');

const PORT = 8080;


const server = https.createServer({
   key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname+'/example.key')),
   cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname+'/example.crt')),
   rejectUnauthorized: false
}, app)



server.listen(PORT, function(){
  console.log(`Listening on https://localhost:${PORT}`);
  //vncClient = new WebSocket.Server({server: server});
//  vncClient = new WebSocket.Server({port: 3000});
//  vncClient.on('connection', new_client);
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection',function (socket) {
console.log("listening..")
});

app.get("/", function(request, response){
     response.send("Hello World").status(200)
});
// server.listen(PORT, function(){                          // ssl commented
//     console.log(`Listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);  // ssl commented
//     vncClient = new WebSocket.Server({port: 3000});        // ssl commented
//     vncClient.on('connection', new_client);                // ssl commented
// });
```